# How to connect to internal API management through an App Gateway externally

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-application-gateway

I have created an internal `APIM` and I have an APP Gateway serving the traffic.  I followed this [this microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-integrate-internal-vnet-appgateway) on **Integrate API Management in an internal virtual network with Application Gateway** and everything works fine. But in that documentation at the end, there's this section:

[image]

But I don't actually understand what it means by **Use the Application Gateway's DNS name to create a CNAME record pointing the API Management gateway hostname (api.contoso.net in the preceding examples) to this DNS name**

Can someone please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

What this means is that you need to point the DNS name of the API Management server to the DNS name of the Application Gateway Server.

so if your APIM server's DNS name is api.contoso.net, you will need to make a CNAME pointing api.contoso.net to your Application Gateway's DNS name (ex traffic-appgw.westus2.cloudapp.azure.com).

so api.contoso.net --(cname)--> traffic-appgw.westus2.cloudapp.azure.com

This way users who navigate to the APIM server are sent to the Application Gateway.

Also, users are served the correct certificate for HTTPS connections. If users went to the Application Gateway's DNS name and were served the certificate for your API server, it can cause the SSL connection to be invalidated.